# Is there any way to shorten this code?

Tags: visual-c++

This is my code on Q&A game on Visual C++

```
             if (this->answer->Text == "2"){
                 this->question->Text = "2+2?";
             }
             else if (this->answer->Text == "4"){
                 this->question->Text = "3+3?";
             }
             else if (this->answer->Text == "6"){
                 this->question->Text = "4+4?";
             }
             else if (this->answer->Text == "8"){
                 this->question->Text = "Finished!";
             }
             else {
                 MessageBox::Show("Wrong!!");
             }
```

Is there any to shorten this code? consider using arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Windows programmer, don't know what the type of your 
`this->question->Text` is, you didn't tell us, but if it is `std::string` or something which can be converted to `char *`, then this should work:

```
std::string t = this->answer->Text;
this->question->Text = t == "2" ? "2+2?"
                     : t == "4" ? "3+3?"
                     : t == "6" ? "4+4?"
                     : t == "8" ? "Finished"
                     : "";
if (this->question->Text = "") MessageBox::Show("Wrong!!");
```

Comment: 1      String t = this->answer->Text;
no suitable user-defined conversion from "System::String ^" to "System::String" exists
2. the "==" has errors too.. "no operator matches these operands, operand types are System::String const char[2]

Comment: @JFetz2191 try `std::string`, not `string` (I updated my answer) and make sure you have `#include <string>` somewhere at the beginning of your source

Answer (score 1):

You're repeating `if (this->answer->Text ==` and `this->question->Text =`. Write those only once and keep the condition and the answer in a std::map.

Update:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
```

...

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> answers;
answers["2"]="2+2"; // "configuration
answers["4"]="3+3?";
//and so on
std::string text=this->answer->Text;
    // instead of if ...
std::map<std::string,std::string>::const_iterator found=answers.find(text);
if (found!=answers.end())
    this->question->Text = answers[text]; //once. Even better found->second
else
    MessageBox::Show("Wrong!!");
```

Comment: How to use std::map with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `switch case` statement.

Comment: "The expression must be of an integral type or of a class type for which there is an unambiguous conversion to integral type", hence no use trying at least here

Comment: Indeed switch case with strings will not work as it compiles to something like jmp+case value